# How to transform DateTime to local time in intl?

Tags: flutter, dart, intl

I have an intl and I want to show local time(15:15, 16:27) but intl shows me 03:16 AM and so on. How can I transfer time to local time?

This is my code:

```
Text(
   DateFormat('hh:mm').format(trackballDetails.point!.x),
   style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 10.sp,
      fontFamily: "Mont"
   ),
)
```

Comment: local time 16:27 in the local timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code just set format like **`HH:mm`** :

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var dateFormate = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a")
      .format(DateTime.parse("2022-09-30 15:15"));
  print(dateFormate);
}
```

Output-> `30-09-2022 15:15 PM`

Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you meet the same problem, try this:

```
var tag = Localizations.maybeLocaleOf(context)?.toLanguageTag();


Text(
   DateFormat.Hm(tag).format(trackballDetails.point!.x),
   style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 10.sp,
      fontFamily: "Mont"
   ),
)
```